# EmberJs - How and where to study?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have started my hands on Ember.js . I have googled and found few tutorials on it. But still finding it difficult. Can anyone suggest me , the order in which things have to be learned like first routing(router,route) then next next. And also learning the syntax, various other functions used. From the very basic to advanced.
 Note: I am a beginner to JavaScript and have a level1 understanding of it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: learn handlbars first

Comment: "I am a beginner to JavaScript and have a level1 understanding of it. ". I'd suggest  learning JavaScript before using a framework.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm not flagging the post because resources are scarce making the risk of opinionated/argumentative answers low, but for future reference, _“questions that ask to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow”_. Good luck on your path, and I'm looking forward to reading your first code questions :)

Answer (score 1):

you can go through [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/), [watch screencasts](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/) and [everything else](http://emberwatch.com/), this resources assume that you know javascript well so learn javascript first then you can move to learning ember.js

Comment: Is there any syntax difference between the normal JavaScript and JavaScript used in Ember. I might be wrong. Just to clarify

Comment: there is no syntactical difference because ember.js is framework written in javascript and for javascript developers, only thing is that Ember.js (if you are using ember-cli) encourages using new version javascript ES6(https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) but you need learn current version of javascript first ES5

Answer (score 1):

This link was really helpfull to me :

http://emberigniter.com/5-essential-ember-2.0-concepts/

and then

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/

It gives you a big picture. I came to Ember from a backbone and angular background. And at first it seemed like a combination of the two since it has this double binding but the models are wrapped in Ember models ember arrays etc.
 If I were you I would start by building simple components running the ember-cli command. 
Of course you'll curse, its kind of part of learning something new. 
The hardest thing for me was Ember-Data, and the fact that there are two many Ember versions, so getting the right documentation is kind of annoying at first.

Hope that links clears some stuff up

Comment: Thank you. And yes getting the right documentation is hard.That link is helpful.